# Setting bit rate and sampling rate-Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mediarecorder

I am working on a Xamarin cross-platform app where in I have a audio recording feature. I have used mediarecorder native android api for recording.

Here is the code:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
recorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);
recorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(44100);
recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
recorder.Prepare();
recorder.Start();
```

The above code doesn't set bit rate and sampling rate to the audio. Since media recorder does not have pause and resume feature I am trying to do that by creating temp file and append the file to new(final) audio file.

Since the sampling and bit rate of two files for merging has to be same, my merge function does not work.

Any help on setting Bit rate and sampling rate?

Comment: you want to merge two audios?

Comment: @Nisarg yes, merging is working but the bit rate and sample rate is not getting set for the recording

Comment: For merging two audios check [this](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) and might be FFMPEG will be helpful

Comment: @Nisarg I have managed to merge audio files, my problem here is setting sample and bit rate. Since the audio I record does not set bit and sample rate merge fails for those audio files. But if I add some external audio files with same sampling and bit rate then my merge function works.

Comment: @Nisarg is mp4Parser available for xamarin? I am developing my app in **Xamarin**.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/leye0/XamarinAndroidMp4Parser)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am still stuck at setting the bit and sample rate for audio. Any help on that?